# How to add 'total' row at bottom of table in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a pivot table with a totals column but am having trouble making a totals row at the bottom of the table using SQL. This is the code I currently have:

```
SELECT
    Committee,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Resume Review'    THEN 1 END) AS "Resume Review",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Interviewing'     THEN 1 END) AS "Interviewing",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Coding Challenge' THEN 1 END) AS "Coding Challenge",
    COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE status IN ('Resume Review', 'Interviewing', 'Coding Challenge')
GROUP BY Committee;
```

which gives this:

```
Committee   Resume Review   Interviewing    Take Home Challenge  Total 
UI/UX              3             2                  1              6
Finance            0             2                  2              4
Marketing          2             4                  1              7
```

I am trying to achieve this:

```
Committee   Resume Review   Interviewing    Take Home Challenge  Total 
UI/UX              3             2                  1              6
Finance            0             2                  2              4
Marketing          2             4                  1              7
Total              5             8                  4              17
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: What you need is closely specific to the DBMS that you're using. Can you tag the DBMS, and preferably it's current version.

Comment: read [Why should I tag DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) please...

Answer (score 2):

You can add 'ROLLUP' to 'GROUP BY'

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(Committee) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE Committee END AS Committee,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Resume Review'    THEN 1 END) AS "Resume Review",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Interviewing'     THEN 1 END) AS "Interviewing",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Coding Challenge' THEN 1 END) AS "Coding Challenge",
    COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE status IN ('Resume Review', 'Interviewing', 'Coding Challenge')
GROUP BY Committee WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: How do you know the OP's database supports it?